# На Береге или на Берегу?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, склонение, названия, существительные

Есть жилой комплекс с названием Звездный Берег.
Как правильно сказать: *Я нахожусь на Звездном береге* или *на Звездном берегу*?

Answer (score 5):

Если вы имеете в виду жилой комплекс (или лагерь, или отель), то нужно использовать предлог "в": ***в** "Звездном Береге"*.
Еще: на письме названия выделяются кавычками.

Правильно:
нахожусь (где? — предложный падеж, стандартное склонение) **в** "Звездном Береге"; купил квартиру **в** "Звездном Береге"; летом был **в** "Звездном Береге".

**В «Береге»** есть все из джентльменского набора развлекательных романов: погони, приключения, путешествия, большие деньги, наркотики, эротические сцены. [Анна Ковалева. Пора на берег. Книги недели // «Известия», 2002.07.31]

Слово "берег" в вашем примере не является краем суши, прилегающим к водоёму.
В этом случае было бы ***на берегу*** (это местный падеж, разновидность предложного): на берегу озера, на берегу водохранилища.

[**Берег**](https://endic.ru/words_forms/Bereg-30130.html)